# saving variable value and retrieve it after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a string value saved in to a variable, my webpage auto reloads after a certain process.. I need to know if I can get the value stored in that variable even after page refresh?

Im refreshing my web page using javascript code `window.location.reload()`

If not will it work if I take to server side script like php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

1. `localStorage` (HTML5 browsers only) - you could save it as a property of the page's local storage allowance
2. save it in a cookie
3. append the variable to the URL hash so it's retrievable via `location.hash` after the refresh

**PHP**

1. save it as a session variable and retrieve it over AJAX each time the page loads
2. save it in a cookie (might as well do the JS approach if you're going to cookie it)

Any PHP approach would be clunky as you'd have to first send the value of the variable to a PHP script over AJAX, then retrieve it over AJAX after reload.

Comment: html5 browsers in the sense my browsers are uptodate..so it should work, right?

Comment: In that case `localStorage` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: one more thing.. how do I clear the localstorage value??

Comment: set: `localStorage.setProperty()`; remove: `localStorage.removeProperty()`

Answer (score 6):

You can store this as a `$_SESSION` variable.

```
session_start();

$myVar = null;

// some code here

if (!isset($_SESSION['myVar'])) {
    $_SESSION['myVar'] = "whatever";
} else {
    $myVar = $_SESSION['myVar'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to persist this variable in a Cookie/Webstorage/Session. Web pages are stateless.

Answer (score 0):

yes you could save your variable on server side as `session` value or on client side in `localstorage` (or as a `cookie`)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are your friend:

```
// Set a cookie or 2
document.cookie = 'somevar=somevalue';
document.cookie = 'another=123';

function getCookie(name)
{
    // Cookies seperated by ;   Key->value seperated by =
    for(var i = 0; pair = document.cookie.split("; ")[i].split("="); i++)
        if(pair[0] == name)
            return unescape(pair[1]);

    // A cookie with the requested name does not exist
    return null;
}

// To get the value
alert(getCookie('somevar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can store that variable into a cookie (the user must have cookies enabled), and then retrieve the cookie after.

The approach is something like this:

**To save**:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 1);
var c_value=escape(value);
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

**To retrieve**:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: mine is a simple string like "Market properties" ..

Comment: ok. you can still use cookies for that