# How to disable submit button after submitting one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to make a function when user submits a form, that button should remain disabled after refreshing the page.
I have tried this method but it only disable for the page when i refresh it can be accessible.

```
<script>
    $('.reverse-form').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to store the button state [in localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which you can then access when the page refreshes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740669/saving-variable-value-and-retrieve-it-after-page-refresh, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the localStorage that is able to store a key-value couple. If a key value isn't present in the localStorage `null` is returned that has `false` boolean value in javascript otherwise whatever string (except empty string "") has `true` boolean value.

Furthermore I used `prop` instead of `attr` because `disabled` is a `boolean attribute` (like checked selected) and in this case you have to use `prop` (otherwise with attr() you set or get the `defaultChecked` property namely the initial value of the disabled attribute, and in this case is the same but in general it isn't so)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form class="reverse-form">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  if (localStorage.submitDisabilitato) {
    $('form.reverse-form input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".reverse-form").one("submit", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      localStorage.submitDisabilitato = "submitDisabilitato";
      $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
    });
  }
</script>
  </body>
```